# double url encoding for ascii charachters

Tags: python, web-applications, character-encoding

What is the used library from python, or how in general the double URL encoding of characters can be done,
example :
character 'a' with URL encoding > %61
character 'a' with double URL encoding > %2561

how I can get the %2561 from 'a'?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your usecase. If you don't need a robust solution you can just use *urllib*

```py
import urllib.parse as parser
encoded_string = "%2561"
decoded_string = parser.unquote(encoded_string) # this would be '%61'
double_decoded_string = parser.unquote(decoded_string) # this would be 'a'
```

You can also remove the decoded_string variable and instead call it like

`double_encoded_string = parser.unquote(parser.unquote(encoded_string))`

From there you could start with looping the decode while it contains encoded_chars etc.